# Not getting the reverse list

Tags: android

I'm parsing the json object taken from server. I want to put the list in reverse order. In order to do that I made a code like this.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = products.length(); i >0; i--){
                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String cid = c.getString(TAG_CID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_CID, cid);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
                Log.d("value", contactList.toString());
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME,}, new int[] {
                        R.id.name});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

If I try to do it in the right order, the list will appear. But if I try reverse, I won't get any output. The problem is in for looping. But cannot findout where it is actually.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is in the loop. The first pass through should throw some sort of "out of bounds" exception, because `products.getJSONObject(products.length())` does not exist. Look in logcat for the details, and/or step through your code with a debugger. Remember, with zero-indexed collections (arrays, lists, etc.) the smallest index value is `0` and the largest is 1 *less* than the total number of elements in the collection.

The fix is to change this:

```
for(int i = products.length(); i >0; i--){
```

to this:

```
for(int i = products.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
```

Answer (score 1):

change your for loop Syntax as Below

```
for(int i = products.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
//  your Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop like this

```
   for(int i = products.length()-1; i >=0; i--){
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

Add this between parsing of json and creating of adapter:

```
Collections.reverse(contactList);
```

Answer (score 0):

To reverse list:-

```
ArrayList<Element> tempElements = new ArrayList<Element>(mElements);
Collections.reverse(tempElements);
```